# Make a loop with a-z input

Tags: java, input

I am a complete noob to Java, but I wish to make a program that takes an input from user, [A/a] - [C/c], [D/d] - [F/f], and so on, and then returns a value ([A/a-C/c = 1], [D/d-F/f = 2]....

If the input is not A-Z or a-z, returns a "Invalid input". (I think I can figure this one out myself).

I suppose I could make a "ToUpperCase" statement on the input, but I am not entirely sure how to do so.

I would prefer not to use any special databases.

Here is my code so far:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TelefonTastatur {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String korrTall = "Korresponderer til tallet "; //Strings are in Norwegian, but I don't need help with those :-)

    System.out.println("Dette programmet konverterer bokstav-input til korresponderende tall på et telefontastatur.");
    System.out.println("Oppgi en bokstav (A-Z: "); //Asks user for A-Z input.

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    char c = sc.next().charAt(0); //Perhaps toUpperCase to lower number of switch cases?

    switch (c) {
        case ('A'-'C'): //Not sure how to make A-C and/or a-c. I could make an individual case for all inputs, but that would make a lot of code.
        case ('a'-'c'):
        System.out.print(korrTall + "2.");
        break;

        case (D/d - F/f):
        case ():
            System.out.print(korrTall + "3.");
        break;

        case (G/g - I/i):
        case ():
            System.out.print(korrTall + "4.");
        break;

        case (J/j - L/l):
        case ():
            System.out.print(korrTall + "5.");
        break;

        case (M/m - O/o):
        case ():
            System.out.print(korrTall + "6.");
        break;

        case (P/p - S/s):
        case ():
            System.out.print(korrTall + "7.");
        break;

        case (T/t - V/v):
        case ():
            System.out.print(korrTall + "8.");
        break;

        case (W/w - Z/z):
        case ():
            System.out.print(korrTall + "9.");
        break;

        case 'F':
        case 'f':
            System.out.print(korrTall + "0.");
        break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Det du har tastet inn tilsvarer ikke noe tall på et telefontastatur.");
        break;  

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are part way there. please try to show how far you have come. Not just your ideas. read [ask] if you need more tips.

Comment: Question is not clear. also post the code you have tried so far and mention the problem you are facing in that code

Comment: Please paste your code in here

Comment: Code is too long. How do I post it?

Comment: You don't need to post your full code, but you do need to post *enough* code to demonstrate the problem. See [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Cool feature with recognizing code in comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use the Scanner class to accomplish user input.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Then create a variable that takes in the keyboard input.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a letter: ");
String text = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Create a method that returns a number given a character.
`a-z` is equal to `97-122` in Java, and `A-Z` is equal to `65-90`.

```
public int toNum(String text) {
  //Ensure that the text is only 1 character long.
  if(text.length() > 1) return -1;

  //Convert the one-character String to type char.
  char letter = text.charAt(0);

  //Convert char to its equivalent number value.
  int rawNum = letter;
  int newNum;

  //Convert the number to a value 0-25.
  if(rawNum >= 'a' && rawNum <= 'z') {
    newNum = rawNum - 'a';
  } else if(rawNum >= 'A' && rawNum <= 'Z') {
    newNum = rawNum - 'A';
  } else {
    //None of the characters were letters A-Z.
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
    return -1;
  }

  //If {a,b,c} are 1 and {d,e,f} are 2, then {0,1,2} -> 1 and {3,4,5} -> 2
  //Take the floor of the new number divided by 3.
  int toReturn = Math.floor(newNum / 3.0) + 1;
  return toReturn;
}
```

Now just call your method with the user input.

```
toNum(text);
```

You can print the returned value of the user input as well.

```
System.out.println(toNum(text));
```

Comment: For clarity, you could replace the numeric values with their corresponding character literals.

Comment: Good thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a single letter from the user you can use the `readInput()`provided in the code snippet.

Then, for example in your `main()`, you could ask for the user to input 2 letters and then you will provide him the result.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            char inputOne = readInput();
            char inputTwo = readInput();
            handle(inputOne,inputTwo);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    static char readInput(){
        System.out.println("Insert a character");
        String input = Console.readLine();
        if (input.length==0) {
            char c = input.charAt(0);
            if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Invalid input!");
    }

    static void handle(char a, char b){
        // your logic to handle the input of the user
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all but i try to help you. Next time post what u tried.

This simple code will help you, this can be improved so let's do this :D

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Insert first char");
String firstChar = scanner.next().toUpperCase();
if (firstChar.length() != 1 || (firstChar.toCharArray()[0] < 65 || firstChar.toCharArray()[0] > 90)) {
    System.out.println("Please, insert one single character [a-z/A-Z]");
    return;
}
System.out.println("Insert second char");
String secondChar = scanner.next().toUpperCase();
if (secondChar.length() != 1 || (secondChar.toCharArray()[0] < 65 || firstChar.toCharArray()[0] > 90)) {
    System.out.println("Please, insert one single character");
    return;
}

System.out.println(firstChar + " - " + secondChar + " = " + Math.abs(firstChar.toCharArray()[0] - secondChar.toCharArray()[0]));
```

Note that You can create methods to do repetitive action. In this simple example you can create a method that check if what you just read from keyboard is a single character.

One other improve you can do is handle when user insert something wrong.

Let's try to code :D
Bye